# Polars: Unnesting columns algorithmically without a for loop

Tags: python-polars

I am working with multiple parquet datasets that were written with nested structs (sometimes multiple levels deep). I need to output a flattened (no struct) schema. Right now the only way I can think to do that is to use for loops to iterate through the columns. Here is a simplified example where I'm for looping.

```
while len([x.name for x in df if x.dtype == pl.Struct]) > 0:
    for col in df:
        if col.dtype == pl.Struct:
            df = df.unnest(col.name)
```

This works, maybe that is the only way to do it, and if so it would be helpful to know that. But Polars is pretty neat and I'm wondering if there is a more functional way to do this without all the looping and reassigning the df to itself.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example? It is hard to give an answer if we have to come up with the data and the expected result as well.

Comment: @ritchie46 I'm guessing they're after something like in my answer.  One question for you, is `unnest` internally parallelized when giving it a list of columns?

Comment: No, an unnest operation is free. :) Wrapping columns in and out of structs is always free if the chunks ar equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a df like this:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5], 'd':[4,5,6], 'e':[5,6,7]}).select([pl.struct(['a','b']).alias('ab'),  pl.struct(['c','d']).alias('cd'),'e'])
```

You can unnest the `ab` and `cd` at the same time by just doing

```
df.unnest(['ab','cd'])
```

If you don't know in advance what your column names and types are in advance then you can just use a list comprehension like this:

```
[col_name for col_name,dtype in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes) if dtype==pl.Struct]
```

We can now just put that list comprehension in the unnest method.

```
df=df.unnest([col_name for col_name,dtype in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes) if dtype==pl.Struct])
```

If you have structs inside structs like:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5], 'd':[4,5,6], 'e':[5,6,7]}).select([pl.struct(['a','b']).alias('ab'),  pl.struct(['c','d']).alias('cd'),'e']).select([pl.struct(['ab','cd']).alias('abcd'),'e'])
```

then I don't think you can get away from some kind of while loop but this might be more concise:

```
while any([x==pl.Struct for x in df.dtypes]):
    df=df.unnest([col_name for col_name,dtype in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes) if dtype==pl.Struct])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a minor addition.  If you're concerned about constantly re-looping through a large number of columns, you can create a recursive formula to address only structs (and nested structs).

```py
def unnest_all(self: pl.DataFrame):
    cols = []
    for next_col in self:
        if next_col.dtype != pl.Struct:
            cols.append(next_col)
        else:
            cols.extend(next_col.struct.to_frame().unnest_all().get_columns())

    return pl.DataFrame(cols)


pl.DataFrame.unnest_all = unnest_all
```

So, using the second example by @Dean MacGregor above:

```py
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4], "c": [
            3, 4, 5], "d": [4, 5, 6], "e": [5, 6, 7]}
    )
    .select([pl.struct(["a", "b"]).alias("ab"), pl.struct(["c", "d"]).alias("cd"), "e"])
    .select([pl.struct(["ab", "cd"]).alias("abcd"), "e"])
)
df
df.unnest_all()
```

```
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────────┬─────┐
│ abcd          ┆ e   │
│ ---           ┆ --- │
│ struct[2]     ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════════╪═════╡
│ {{1,2},{3,4}} ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {{2,3},{4,5}} ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {{3,4},{5,6}} ┆ 7   │
└───────────────┴─────┘
>>> df.unnest_all()
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

And using the first example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4], "c": [
        3, 4, 5], "d": [4, 5, 6], "e": [5, 6, 7]}
).select([pl.struct(["a", "b"]).alias("ab"), pl.struct(["c", "d"]).alias("cd"), "e"])
df
df.unnest_all()
```

```
>>> df
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ ab        ┆ cd        ┆ e   │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ struct[2] ┆ struct[2] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ {1,2}     ┆ {3,4}     ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {2,3}     ┆ {4,5}     ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {3,4}     ┆ {5,6}     ┆ 7   │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────┘
>>> df.unnest_all()
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In the end, I'm not sure that this saves you much wall-clock time (or RAM).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers taught me a lot. I encountered a new situation where I wanted to easily be able to get each column labeled with all the structs it came from. i.e. for

```py
pl.col("my").struct.field("test").struct.field("thing")
```

I wanted to recover

`my.test.thing`

as a string which I could easily use when reading a subset of columns with pyarrow via

```py
pq.ParquetDataset(path).read(columns = ["my.test.thing"])
```

Since there are many hundreds of columns and the nesting can go quite deep, I wrote functions to do a depth first search on the schema, extract the columns in that pyarrow friendly format, then I can use those to select each column unnested all in one go.

First, I worked with the pyarrow schema because I couldn't figure out how to drill into the structs in the polars schema:

```
schema = df.to_arrow().schema
```

navigating structs in that schema is quirky, at the top level the structure behaves differently from deeper in. I ended up writing two functions, the first to navigate the top level structure and the second to continue the search below:

```py
def schema_top_level_DFS(pa_schema):
    top_level_stack = list(range(len(pa_schema)))
    while top_level_stack:
        working_top_level_index = top_level_stack.pop()
        working_element_name = pa_schema.names[working_top_level_index]
        if type(pa_schema.types[working_top_level_index]) == pa.lib.StructType:
            second_level_stack = list(range(len(pa_schema.types[working_top_level_index])))
            while second_level_stack:
                working_second_level_index = second_level_stack.pop()
                schema_DFS(pa_schema.types[working_top_level_index][working_second_level_index],working_element_name)
        else:
            column_paths.append(working_element_name)


def schema_DFS(incoming_element,upstream_names):
    current_name = incoming_element.name
    combined_names = ".".join([upstream_names,current_name])
    if type(incoming_element.type) == pa.lib.StructType:
        stack = list(range(len(incoming_element.type)))
        while stack:
            working_index = stack.pop()
            working_element = incoming_element.type[working_index]
            schema_DFS(working_element,combined_names)
    else:
        column_paths.append(combined_names)
```

So that running

```py
column_paths = []
schema_top_level_DFS(schema)
```

gives me column paths like

```py
['struct_name_1.inner_struct_name_2.thing1','struct_name_1.inner_struct_name_2.thing2]
```

to actually do the unnesting, I wasn't sure how to do better than a function with a case statement:

```py
def return_pl_formatting(col_string):
    col_list = col_string.split(".")
    match len(col_list):
        case 1:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).alias(col_string)
        case 2:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).struct.field(col_list[1]).alias(col_string)
        case 3:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).struct.field(col_list[1]).struct.field(col_list[2]).alias(col_string)
        case 4:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).struct.field(col_list[1]).struct.field(col_list[2]).struct.field(col_list[3]).alias(col_string)
        case 5:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).struct.field(col_list[1]).struct.field(col_list[2]).struct.field(col_list[3]).struct.field(col_list[4]).alias(col_string)
        case 6:
            return pl.col(col_list[0]).struct.field(col_list[1]).struct.field(col_list[2]).struct.field(col_list[3]).struct.field(col_list[4]).struct.field(col_list[5]).alias(col_string)
```

Then get my unnested and nicely named df with:

```py
df.select([return_pl_formatting(x) for x in column_paths])
```

To show the output on the example from @Dean MacGregor

```py
test = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4], "c": [
            3, 4, 5], "d": [4, 5, 6], "e": [5, 6, 7]}
    )
    .select([pl.struct(["a", "b"]).alias("ab"), pl.struct(["c", "d"]).alias("cd"), "e"])
    .select([pl.struct(["ab", "cd"]).alias("abcd"), "e"])
)
column_paths = []
schema_top_level_DFS(test.to_arrow().schema)
print(test.select([return_pl_formatting(x) for x in column_paths]))
```

```
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ e   ┆ abcd.cd.d ┆ abcd.cd.c ┆ abcd.ab.b ┆ abcd.ab.a │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 5   ┆ 4         ┆ 3         ┆ 2         ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ 5         ┆ 4         ┆ 3         ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 6         ┆ 5         ┆ 4         ┆ 3         │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I'm a novice in python, polars, and all things so I don't know if this was a good idea. But I'll leave what I did here in case anyone ever considers doing the same and wants to build off what I did. Or even better if anyone can offer improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will un-nest all columns recursively. As it uses only column references, it is not compute intensive.

```
import polars as pl
test = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4], "c": [
            3, 4, 5], "d": [4, 5, 6], "e": [5, 6, 7]}
    )
    .select([pl.struct(["a", "b"]).alias("ab"), pl.struct(["c", "d"]).alias("cd"), "e"])
    .select([pl.struct(["ab", "cd"]).alias("abcd"), "e"])
)

def unnest(column, type_):
    if column.dtype == pl.Struct:
        cols = []
        for field in type_.fields:
            col = column.struct.field(field.name)
            normalized = unnest(col, field.dtype)
            cols.extend(
                [v.alias(f"{column.name}.{v.name}") for v in normalized]
            )
        return cols
    else:
        return [column]

def unnest_df(df):
    schema = df.schema

    cols = []

    for next_col in df:
        cols.extend(
            unnest(next_col, schema[next_col.name])
        )

    df = pl.DataFrame(
        cols
    )

    return df

test = unnest_df(test).to_pandas()
```