# Polars table convert a list column to separate rows i.e. unnest a list column to multiple rows

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe in the form:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[['a','b'],['a'],['c','d']]})
```

```
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b          │
│ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]  │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "b"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["a"]      │
│ 3   ┆ ["c", "d"] │
└─────┴────────────┘
```

I want to convert it to the following form.  I plan to save to a parquet file, and query the file (with sql).

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ "a" │
│ 1   ┆ "b" │
│ 2   ┆ "a" │
│ 3   ┆ "c" │
│ 3   ┆ "d" │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I have seen an [answer that works on struct columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638704/polars-unnesting-columns-algorithmically-without-a-for-loop), but `df.unnest('b')` on my data results in the error:

```
SchemaError: Series of dtype: List(Utf8) != Struct
```

I also found [a github issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3282) that shows list can be converted to a struct, but I can't work out how to do that, or if it applies here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To decompose column with `Lists`, you can use `.explode()` method ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html))

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[['a','b'],['a'],['c','d']]})

df.explode("b")
```

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ a   │
│ 1   ┆ b   │
│ 2   ┆ a   │
│ 3   ┆ c   │
│ 3   ┆ d   │
└─────┴─────┘
```