# How to unnest multiple struct columns with similar Structs in Polars, using disambiguating suffix

Tags: python-polars

I have 2 columns with similar Structs (same field names, field types, etc.).

```py
nest = pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[{'x':1,'y':10},{'x':2,'y':20},],
    'b':[{'x':3,'y':30},{'x':4,'y':40},]    
})
print(nest)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ struct[2] ┆ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ {1,10}    ┆ {3,30}    │
│ {2,20}    ┆ {4,40}    │
└───────────┴───────────┘

print(nest.schema)
{'a': Struct([Field('x', Int64), Field('y', Int64)]), 
 'b': Struct([Field('x', Int64), Field('y', Int64)])}
```

I want to unnest both those columns and get a flat data frame, with the fields suffixed to disambiguate them:

```py
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x_a ┆ y_a ┆ x_b ┆ y_b │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 30  │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ 40  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I tried:

```py
nest.unnest('a','b')
```

but (of course) got `DuplicateError` for the names `x` and `y`.

Ideally something that will recursively flatten & disambiguate names using field paths :-(

Answer (score 2):

**[Update]:** [`.name.map_fields()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.map_fields.html#polars.Expr.name.map_fields) has since been added which could perhaps be useful.

---

May be relevant: [Polars: Unnesting columns algorithmically without a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638704/)

There are also a few issues on the tracker around prefix/suffix customization:

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9613
- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9790

You can manually loop over the schema:

```py
nest.with_columns(
   [
      pl.col(col).struct.rename_fields(
         [f'{field.name}_{col}' for field in nest.schema[col].fields]
      )
      for col in nest.schema
   ]
).unnest('a', 'b')
```

```py
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x_a ┆ y_a ┆ x_b ┆ y_b │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 30  │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ 40  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

But it's not a true, recursive solution.

---

Recursion is rather more involved, and there is no "built in" solution as of yet.

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12353

```py
def _unnest_schema(schema, separator=".", reverse=False):
    def _walk_schema(schema, path=[]):
        for name, dtype in schema.items():
            base_type = dtype.base_type()
            if base_type == pl.Struct:
                yield from _walk_schema(dtype.to_schema(), path + [name])
            else:
                yield path + [name], dtype
                
    for (col, *fields), dtype in _walk_schema(schema):
        expr = pl.col(col)
        
        for field in fields:
            expr = expr.struct[field]
            
        if col != "":
           fields = [col] + fields
           
        if reverse:
           fields = reversed(fields)
        
        yield expr.alias(separator.join(fields))
```

```py
for expr in _unnest_schema(nest.schema, separator="_", reverse=True):
    print(f"{expr.meta.output_name()=}")
# expr.meta.output_name()='x_a'
# expr.meta.output_name()='y_a'
# expr.meta.output_name()='x_b'
# expr.meta.output_name()='y_b'
```

```py
nest.select(
   _unnest_schema(nest.schema, separator="_", reverse=True)
)

# shape: (2, 4)
# ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
# │ x_a ┆ y_a ┆ x_b ┆ y_b │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 30  │
# │ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ 40  │
# └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of unnest is to error when it encounters duplicate columns. There's not a built in way to do what you're looking to do. I wrote this alternative `unnest` which does what you're looking for. You can monkey patch it to your `pl.DataFrame` namespace so you can use it directly...

```
def unnest(self, columns, *more_columns, prefix=None, suffix=None, col_prefix=False, col_suffix=False, drop_existing=False):
    if isinstance(columns, str):
        columns = [columns]
    if more_columns:
        columns = list(columns)
        columns.extend(more_columns)
    #check to see if any new parameters are used, if not just return as is current behavior
    if drop_existing==False and not (prefix or suffix or col_prefix or col_suffix):
        return self._from_pydf(self._df.unnest(columns))
    final_prefix=""
    final_suffix=""
    
    for col in columns:
        if col_prefix:
            final_prefix=col+"_"+prefix if prefix else col+"_"
        if col_suffix:
            final_suffix="_"+col+suffix if suffix else "_"+col
        tempdf = self[0].select(col)
        innercols = tempdf._from_pydf(tempdf._df.unnest([col])).columns
        newcols = [final_prefix+innercol+final_suffix for innercol in innercols]
        self = (
            self
                .with_columns(pl.col(col).struct.rename_fields(newcols))
                .drop([drop_col for drop_col in newcols if drop_col in self.columns])
        )
    return self._from_pydf(self._df.unnest(columns))
pl.DataFrame.unnest=unnest
```

After you do that then you can do what you're looking to do with just a parameter setting in my unnest

```
nest.unnest('a','b', col_suffix=True)
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x_a ┆ y_a ┆ x_b ┆ y_b │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 30  │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ 40  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```